# I got blank email every time when i refresh web page

Tags: php, forms

```
//*This is my php code,when i load page its sent blank e mail i tried everything but i did not finde solution 
    <?php 

     // validate each of the variables in the form 
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     $name = $_POST['name']; 
     $email = $_POST['email']; 
     $job = $_POST['job']; 
     $grad = $_POST['grad'];
     $pocetak = $_POST ['pocetak'];
     $vozacka = $_POST ['vozacka'];
     $CV = $_POST ['CV'];
     $daysavailable = $_POST['daysavailable']; 
     $telefon = $_POST['telefon']; 
     }

     // add date the form was submitted 
     $date = gmdate("M d Y"); 

     // Thank the user 
    print "Hvala! $name Javit cemo Vam se uskoro.."; 
    print "$date";

     // Send to specificed email address 
    $to ="damirsalkic@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Aplikacija za posao"; 
    $body =" 
    Date: $date 
    \n Ime i prezime: $name 
    \n Email address: $email 
    \n Telefon: $telefon
    \n Posao za koji aplicirate: $job 
    \n Grad u kojem aplicirate za posao: $grad 
    \n Da li posjedujete vozačku dozvolu: $vozacka 
    \n Kad možete početi: $pocetak
    \n Kratki CV: $CV  
    \n Days available: $daysavailable[0] $daysavailable[1] 
    $daysavailable[2] $daysavailable[4] 
     \n\n"; 
     mail($to,$subject,$body);    
    ?>
```

//* Can someone help mi with this problem ?

```
<form> 

  <p>Aplikacija za posao / postanite dio naše porodice - Bingo</p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Vaše ime i prezime :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Vaš e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="contact">Vaš broj telefona :</label>
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="job">Izaberite poziciju za koju aplicirate !</label>
    <select name="job" id="job">
      <option value="pravnik">Pravnik</option>
      <option value="komercijalista">Komercijalista</option>
      <option value="prodavač">Prodavač</option>
      <option value="skladištar">Skladištar</option>
      <option value="Vozač">Vozač</option>
      <option value="pripravnik">Pripravnik</option>
      <option value="grafički dizajner">Grafički dizajner</option>
      <option value="informatički tehničar">Informatički tehničar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="grad"><br />
      <br />
      Navedite grad u kojem aplicirate za posao: </label>
    <input type="text" name="grad" id="grad" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="pocetak">Kad možete početi ?</label>
    <input type="text" name="pocetak" id="pocetak" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="vozacka">Da li posjedujete vozacku dozvolu ?</label>
    <select name="vozacka" id="vozacka">
      <option value="da">Da</option>
      <option value="ne">Ne</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CV">Ovo je mjesto za Vaš kratki CV<br />
    </label>
    <textarea name="CV" id="CV" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" /></form>
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur malesuada magna in eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris ac urna ac mauris tristique condimentum sit amet id erat. Aenean in purus eu arcu feugiat posuere. Nullam eu accumsan magna. Nunc tristique fermentum tortor, sit amet imperdiet tortor volutpat in. Quisque imperdiet dolor at dapibus sodales. Donec at eleifend tortor. Nunc magna massa, condimentum in nisl vel, elementum mattis felis. Nulla quis feugiat ante. Quisque congue interdum elit, eget sagittis libero elementum ac.

Comment: You call the mail function on every page load. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you fix it because I'm not an expert in php ? PLs

Comment: you should have just closed your if at the end of the script and not after you declared the variables.

Comment: Is that lorem ipsum stuff supposed to be part of your code, or just an annoying way to evade SO's quality filter?

Comment: @NicoO Then the script does not work...Do you have another idea ?

Comment: damir look at my example, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the form and the php are on the same page code below works

new form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post"> 

  <p>Aplikacija za posao / postanite dio naše porodice - Bingo</p>

  <p>
    <label for="name">Vaše ime i prezime :</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Vaš e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="contact">Vaš broj telefona :</label>
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="job">Izaberite poziciju za koju aplicirate !</label>
    <select name="job" id="job">
      <option value="pravnik">Pravnik</option>
      <option value="komercijalista">Komercijalista</option>
      <option value="prodavač">Prodavač</option>
      <option value="skladištar">Skladištar</option>
      <option value="Vozač">Vozač</option>
      <option value="pripravnik">Pripravnik</option>
      <option value="grafički dizajner">Grafički dizajner</option>
      <option value="informatički tehničar">Informatički tehničar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="grad"><br />
      <br />
      Navedite grad u kojem aplicirate za posao: </label>
    <input type="text" name="grad" id="grad" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="pocetak">Kad možete početi ?</label>
    <input type="text" name="pocetak" id="pocetak" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="vozacka">Da li posjedujete vozacku dozvolu ?</label>
    <select name="vozacka" id="vozacka">
      <option value="da">Da</option>
      <option value="ne">Ne</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CV">Ovo je mjesto za Vaš kratki CV<br />
    </label>
    <textarea name="CV" id="CV" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" /></form>
```

and php code

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

//*This is my php code,when i load page its sent blank e mail i tried everything but i did not finde solution 


 // validate each of the variables in the form 

 $name = $_POST['name']; 
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $job = $_POST['job']; 
 $grad = $_POST['grad'];
 $pocetak = $_POST ['pocetak'];
 $vozacka = $_POST ['vozacka'];
 $CV = $_POST ['CV'];
 $daysavailable = $_POST['daysavailable']; 
 $telefon = $_POST['telefon']; 


 // add date the form was submitted 
 $date = gmdate("M d Y"); 

 // Thank the user 
print "Hvala! $name Javit cemo Vam se uskoro.."; 
print "$date";

 // Send to specificed email address 
$to ="damirsalkic@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Aplikacija za posao"; 
$body =" 
Date: $date 
\n Ime i prezime: $name 
\n Email address: $email 
\n Telefon: $telefon
\n Posao za koji aplicirate: $job 
\n Grad u kojem aplicirate za posao: $grad 
\n Da li posjedujete vozačku dozvolu: $vozacka 
\n Kad možete početi: $pocetak
\n Kratki CV: $CV  
\n Days available: $daysavailable[0] $daysavailable[1] 
$daysavailable[2] $daysavailable[4] 
 \n\n"; 
 mail($to,$subject,$body);    
}
?>
```

Comment: yes it does, you have some other issues then. if you copy what i wrote and POST to the page, the email will send .

you need to add method=post to your <form> tag as well as an action=""

Comment: Perhaps a form is problem...Can you take a look ?

Comment: you are my friend ...tnx a lote :D